# Periods of Coxeter transformation associated to root posets

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, lattice-theory, posets

$\DeclareMathOperator\Co{Co}$Let $P$ be the root poset associated to a simple Lie algebra.

Let $L=L(P)$ denote the distributive lattice of order ideals of $P$ and let $\Co_L$ denote the Coxeter matrix of $L(P)$ which is defined as $-C^{-1} C^T$ when $C$ is the matrix with entries $c_{i,j}=1$ when $i \leq j$ and $c_{i,j}=0$ else for $i,j \in L$.

> Question: For which types is the matrix $\Co_L$ periodic? That is when do we have $\Co_L^t=\operatorname{id}$ for some $t \geq 1$? What is the period (the smallest such $t$) in case this is true for a given type?

The quesiton has a positive answer for all simple Lie algebras of rank at most 6. So maybe it is always periodic?

For $A_n$ it is $2n+4$ for $n=2,3,4,5,6$ but for $A_1$ it is 3. Is it $2n+4$ in general for $n \geq 2$?

For $D_4$ it is 14 and for $D_5$ it is 18 and for $D_6$ it is 22. Is it given by $4n-2$?

For $B_2$ it is 10 and for $B_3$ it is 7 and for $B_4$ it is 18 and for $B_5$ it is 11 and for $B_6$ it is 26. Is it $8n+2$ for $B_{2n}$? Is it $4n+3$ for $B_{2n+1}$?

For $G_2$ it is 14 and for $F_4$ it is 26 and for $E_6$ it is 26.

edit: I saw that in the introduction of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10632.pdf there is a conjecture of Chapoton stated that says the the incidence algebras of those distributive lattices are fractionally Calabi-Yau. The truth of this conjecture would imply a positive answer to the question of this thread.

Comment: Is the period always $2*(h+1)$ where $h$ is the Coxeter number?

Comment: @SamHopkins For $B_3$ it is 7.

Comment: It seems that the period could be $h+1$ or $2(h+1)$.

Comment: It seems the first nonnegative entry in the row of $-C^{-1}C^T$ indexed by $i \in L$ is $\mathrm{Row}(i)$, the rowmotion of the order ideal (a.k.a., the Panyushev map). Since root posets are known to have good behavior of rowmotion (see https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.3353 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1277), this may be key to your observation (although note that the order of rowmotion is $2h$ or $h$, slightly different than what you see here). Rowmotion appeared in another related Q of yours: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343203/permanent-of-the-coxeter-matrix-of-a-distributive-lattice

Comment: @SamHopkins I added more terms and some guesses for the types. For type $A_n$ and $D_n$ it seems to behave regular, while for type $B_n$ one might have to split into even and odd cases.

Comment: Let $M:=-C^{-1}C^T$. Let $D$ denote the permutation matrix of the action of rowmotion. Thus $MD$ is lower-triangular by my previous comment (which is actually proved in the linked to MO question). It seems that we may always have that $(MD)^2$ is the identity. I feel like this must be related to your problem somehow.

Comment: You can see Sage code here: https://cocalc.com/share/0efb266aca1eef099315e87e1750671ee5737323/root_poset_coxeter_transformation.sagews?viewer=share

Comment: @SamHopkins That is a nice observation. I will try to see where it might come from in case this identity is true.

Comment: Another comment: the $h+1$/$2(h+1)$ order also appears in the paper of Yildirim you link to. She shows $\tau^{h+1}=\pm 1$, in the context of minuscule posets (rather than root posets).

Comment: @SamHopkins Isnt this conjecture 5.5. in the article?

Comment: You're right. It's proved there in most cases, but not quite all.